# This localhost page can’t be found :Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Suddenly I am facing This localhost page can’t be found, No webpage was found for the web address: `https://localhost:9002/de` issue in my site.

`hosts` file is set as :

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

and #Site URL Configurations

```
website.DEB2CStore.http=https://localhost:9002/de
website.DEB2CStore.https=https://localhost:9002/de
```

Comment: Although, hac ,backoffice, productcockpit all are working fine.

Comment: I have changed the status of one pending answer,Thanks. Can you hep me out in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

That is rough to say what here is the problem. This can have multiple reasons. But I think the mostly problem is, thar your storefront configuration doesn't match with your `hosts` file.

Here you can find some information about [storefront configuration](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4c33bf189ab9409e84e589295c36d96e/2005/en-US/8abf404186691014aa22afd908b7fc30.html).

> **Accessing the Accelerator Storefronts**
>
> To access the sample storefronts you need to add a localhost mapping
> to your computer's hosts file. The hosts file approach requires an
> extra setup step on your machine and it represents how storefronts are
> organized in terms of domain URLs in a production environment.

The point is, that Hybris tries to map the given url with the correct storefront. If you give him only `localhost` he dont't know what to do. You can check if your 'normal' Hybris setup is right by trying this url:

```
http://localhost:9001/yacceleratorstorefront?site=apparel-uk&clear=true
```

For the 'normal' setup your `hosts` file should look like:

```
127.0.0.1 apparel-uk.local apparel-de.local electronics.local powertools.local
```